# Christmas Hats 2013 Edition!

Tags: discussion, support, fun

It's December!

For the past couple of years, many SF'ers have added Santa hats to their Gravatars For Christmas.  Feel free to join in, here are the hats we've used in the past:

[image: basic hat]

or

[image: fancy hat]

Answer (score 9):

This is @DennisKaarsemaker's hat! ***U NO CAN HAZ!!***

[image: No seriously. You can't have it.]

Bow before my superior photoshop skillz, catmonster:

[image: I can]

Comment: It looks like Dennis is trying to rip the brainslug hat of christmas cheer off his head before it gets to his soul.... I heartily approve this gravatar!

Answer (score 9):

[image: jingle]

Answer (score 9):

Since Wesley hasn't bothered to make me a better one yet I'm still using my hackjob from **Two Years Ago**.

[image]

UPDATE: I (wesley) had a little trouble covering up the pre-existing hat, but think I did okay:

[image]

Update Deux: I don't want to discuss how I acquired the source image. Ever.

[image: No. Just no.]

Update Trois: This is less insane and facing the correct direction.
[image]

Comment: You just *had* to go and make things awkward by already having a hat on, didn't you.

Comment: @Wesley: You want me to go find something that doesn't have me wearing a hat?

Answer (score 7):

[image: hello]

Answer (score 6):

I put a hat on @RyanRies butt!

[image: Ryan Ries's Santa Butt]

Answer (score 6):

I put a hat on Mark Marra's cat and some guy sitting in Mark's chair!

[image: Mark's cat in a hat!]

Answer (score 5):

Deck the halls with tales of folly, Fa Ladadadada...

[image: Sorry that's the best I can do.]

Answer (score 4):

[image: enter link description here]

He does know in fact, if you've been naughty or nice (or a cat.)

Answer (score 3):

Shortly after this picture was taken, Maui peed on the hat.

[image: Maui pees on everything!]

Answer (score 3):

It's like the avatar was made for a hat!

[image: Jenny Jenny Jenny!]

Answer (score 3):

What is the square root of Santa?

[image: I don't know.]

Or maybe what is the Santa root of -1?

[image: Who knows?]

Answer (score 2):

@MathiasR.Jessen might be facing the wrong way, but at least he has a hat to cover his shame.

[image: SHAAAAAAAME!!]

Alternate option:

[image: DUDE WHERE'S MY CAR]

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what I'm doing with a Santa hat.

[image: Dog with trowel]

Answer (score 2):

Look at Santa's little snappy dressing helper!

[image: Jeff "Facebook" Ferland in the hizouse!]

Comment: Hark! What vile cretin would downvote such a mensch!

Answer (score 2):

Jingle Jingle Jingle
Here's comes Tom'OConnor

[image: Jingle Jingle Jingle]

Answer (score 2):

I might not be able to put my butt on a bike, but I can at least put a hat on a bike!

[image: HAT ON A BIKE!]

Answer (score 2):

it's DanBig with... a hat. On a phone. Yeah that's all I got.

[image: It's a nice hat!]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bah! Humbug!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: white fang]

Answer (score 1):

Yo dawg! I heard @JourneymanGeek's dog likes hats!

[image: JourneymanDawg]

Answer (score 1):

Now I'll only need to make 3.4×10^38-1 more hats!

[image: I pee vee six. Should I see a doctor? =(]

Answer (score 1):

Feliz Navidog!

[image: It's funny! Laugh!]

Answer (score 1):

@ChrisS rocks the santa hat ***with*** a suit.

[image: AWW YISS.]

Answer (score 1):

@faker might have a fake moustache, but his hat is straight up legit!

[image: +1 for hipster Santa.]

Answer (score 1):

@pauska is probably more closely related to [Krampus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus) than Kris Kringle, but hey...

[image: RAWR!]

Answer (score 1):

I had to get a running start for the hat to fit over the mohawk, but in the end it was worth it!

[image: The spikes help it stay on in the wind!]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The Brazilian Jesus is afraid to lose his hat (said hat courtesy of @JourneymanGeek)

Answer (score 1):

Snookums got a Santa hat!

[image: Purrrrr.]

Update: Thanks! But I think I will use my one from last year to mix it up a bit!

[image: bung]

Answer (score 1):

RobertM's ancient gato, who does not live in Canada:

[image: El gato]

Comment: Thank you :) [tag:die-markdown-die]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you're naughty or nice, his axe is still shiny.

[image: DON'T MESS WITH HIS AXE!]

Comment: He has no axe, he has a boomershooter!

Answer (score 1):

Business cat needs help wrapping the red dot.

[image: SRSBIZ]

Answer (score 1):

Try as @Dan may, hey can't outrun the hat!

[image: RUN RUN RUN AS FAST AS YOU CAN!]

Answer (score 1):

I have a hat on my head!

[image: hat]

Answer (score 1):

You 'gellin? He's 'gellin.

[image: No really.]

Answer (score 1):

Good thing he's already in the sky because now he can sleighjack Santa!

[image: Do it to it!]

Answer (score 1):

Nathan can haz hat.

[image: Nathan can haz hat.]

Answer (score 1):

To the only person amongst us truly built to play Santa:

[image: Seriously. He's huge.]

Answer (score 1):

It's @jcolekringle!

[image: KILL THE MONKEYS!]

Answer (score 1):

Since Peter is ashamed to hang out with us anymore, he can now come visit without anyone recognizing him:

[image: SHUTTUP, GUILT WORKS!]

Answer (score 0):

I put a hat on Pato's pate!

[image: Pato's behatted pate.]

Answer (score 0):

IS SANTA HAT, COMRADE.

[image: Daniel]

Answer (score 0):

Goatmale modeling our newest Santa hat in roguish fashion:

[image: He's a goat! He's male!]

Answer (score 0):

Is Mike. Is Nice.

[image: Mike]

Answer (score 0):

Oliver Santazburg.

[image: Silent Nocht.]

Answer (score 0):

SPACEMAN KRINGLE

[image: No.]

Answer (score 0):

Merry Christmas, @Basil!

[image: for basil]

Answer (score 0):

Does a Bear wear a Santa hat in the forest?

[image: No but he poops a lot.]

Answer (score 0):

Corporate Mundo? More like Corporate Santa. (Wow, I'm really scraping the bottom of the barrel tonight.)

[image: Sigh.]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have enough of @freiheit's head to work with, so I had to improvise:

[image: He does have a nice beard.]

Okay, second try:

[image: Eric Moorehead]

And the version @freiheit made with http://santahat.me/ and is actually using:

[image: Santa Hat dot Me]

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked me to do this for them but I don't know who!

[image: WHO IS THIS?!]