# Christmas Hats 2014 Edition

Tags: discussion, fun

Maybe it's time for a change?  But for the past couple of years, many SF'ers have added Santa hats to their Gravatars For Christmas.  If you already have a Gravatar with a hat it's easy to activate it again, for anyone who wants to add a hat, here are the ones we've used in the past:

[image: basic hat]

or

[image: fancy hat]

[(Last year's hats, mostly by Wesley.)](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5947/christmas-hats-2013-edition?rq=1)

Comment: Also, the Winter Bash hats will be back soon for your double-hat needs.

Comment: So, how do I put my hat on?

Answer (score 2):

How to use these hats:

- Basically, just download the hat image from this Q and paste it over top of your existing Gravatar.
- If you don't already have an uploaded picture as your Gravatar, this might be the time to do it, but you can just paste it over your automatic gravatar, e.g.

[image]

Comment: You mean by editing my user picture in an image editor and uploading the new image?  Sure, I could do that any time.  But a year or two ago there was a checkbox somewhere that automatically gave me a hat, without making me edit my user picture.  Is that gone?

Comment: You're thinking of the Winter Bash promotion that SE has done for the past couple of years:  http://stackexchange.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013  It sounds like that will happen again, but altering our Gravatars for Christmas is something we on SF started doing the year before Winter Bash: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2394/its-santa-time

Comment: And here I am still attached to my BOFH gravatar.